# Find the MLE of a GLM

Tags: statistics, summation, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood, logistic-regression

> (Note this is not an assignment, but revision for a topic from Cambridge past exam papers) I have been trying to attempt the below question, and I am struggling with part (b).
>
> [image]

***For (a)*** it is obvious that the pmf is the same as the Bernoulli and so

$$ f(y;p) = \exp\left(y\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)+\log(1-p) \right).$$

***Then for (b)***, the log-likelihood is given by 
$$\ell(\beta,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i\log\left(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right)+\log(1-p_i) \right)$$

Now, $\log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta^Tx \Rightarrow \log(1-p) = \log(p) - \beta^Tx$

And so,

\begin{align}
\ell(\beta,y) &= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\beta^Tx_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \log(p) - \sum_{i=1}^n \beta^Tx_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\beta^Tx_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(\frac{e^{\beta^Tx}}{1+e^{\beta^Tx}}\right) - \sum_{i=1}^n \beta^Tx_i
\end{align}

And i am unsure how to deal with this middle term, particularly when differentiating, as i cannot get the final answer.

Comment: I think you should have: $$f(y;p) = \exp\left(y\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)+\log(1-p) \right).$$

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Nice question. Ping me in 24 hours and maybe I'll look at it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $β = (β_1, \cdots, β_p)^{\mathrm{T}}$ and $x_i = (x_{i1}, \cdots, x_{ip})^{\mathrm{T}}$, then $β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^p β_j x_{ij}$. Since $\displaystyle p_i(β) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i}}$,\begin{align*}
L(β; y) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(y_i \ln\left(\frac{p_i(β)}{1 - p_i(β)}\right) + \ln(1 - p_i(β))\right)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(y_i β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i + \ln\left(\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i}}\right)\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i - \ln(1 + \mathrm{e}^{β^{\mathrm{T}} x_i}))\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \sum_{j = 1}^p β_j x_{ij} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \ln\left(1 + \exp\left(\sum_{j = 1}^p β_j x_{ij}\right)\right).
\end{align*}
For each $1 \leqslant k \leqslant p$,$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial β_k}(β; y) = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_{ik} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\exp\left(\sum\limits_{j = 1}^p β_j x_{ij}\right)}{1 + \exp\left(\sum\limits_{j = 1}^p β_j x_{ij}\right)} \cdot x_{ik} = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_{ik} - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(β) x_{ik}.
$$
Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial L}{\partial β_k}(\hat{β}; y) = 0 \ (1 \leqslant k \leqslant p)$, thus\begin{align*}
0 &= \sum_{k = 1}^p \hat{β}_k \frac{\partial L}{\partial β_k}(\hat{β}; y) = \sum_{k = 1}^p \hat{β}_k \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_{ik} - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(\hat{β}) x_{ik}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \sum_{k = 1}^p \hat{β}_k x_{ik} - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(\hat{β}) \sum_{k = 1}^p \hat{β}_k x_{ik} = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \hat{β}^{\mathrm{T}} x_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(\hat{β}) \hat{β}^{\mathrm{T}} x_i\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mathop{\mathrm{logit}}(p_i(\hat{β})) - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(\hat{β}) \mathop{\mathrm{logit}}(p_i(\hat{β})),
\end{align*}
which implies$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(\hat{β}) \mathop{\mathrm{logit}}(p_i(\hat{β})) = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mathop{\mathrm{logit}}(p_i(\hat{β})).
$$